# ggplot2: Import transparent-background PNG logo into R

Tags: r, ggplot2, png

Having trouble inserting PNG logo from desktop and having it integrate with the ggplot chart below. I read there were issues using raster with on Windows platform but can't be sure if that's the case.

```
   library(png)
    library(grid)
    library(ggplot2) 
    library(reshape2)

    img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
    g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

    df <- melt(economics[, c("date", "psavert", "uempmed")], id="date")

    ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
          geom_line(aes(color = variable), size=1) +
          scale_color_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00")) +
          theme_minimal() +
          annotation_custom(g, xmin=as.numeric(as.Date("1980-01-01")), xmax=as.numeric(as.Date("1990-01-01")), ymin=-Inf, ymax=5)
```

Also, I imported my logo but the image is either just a black box or a white box and not displaying the logo. How can I resolve this issue? I checked to ensure the logo.PNG wasn't encrypted or protected. Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you manually saved an image `picture123.png` in the `png/img` folder? `system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")` creates a pth to the png, so it needs to exist there. Otherwise, just pass the path to the image you want to plot.

Comment: okay, then just use the path to that then: `readPNG("path/to/desktop/img_folder/picture123.png")`

Comment: What does this return: `file.exists("C:/Users/ma77fred2/Desktop/logo123.png")`

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Can you please tell mw how to move the logo in the lower left etc? Thanks again!

Comment: change the coordinates to suit: `annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=5)`

Comment: Hi, I just tried adjusting the xmin and xmax by different integers and doesn't show up on the chart.

Comment: Can you edit your question please , showing the code you used, and why it doesn't work. Include ant errors / messages as well please. (Use `system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")` in your example so it is reproducible)

Comment: thanks for updating. You are missing the readPNG ie `img <- readPNG(...`.  But when you give the coordinates to annotation you have to give them in the correct units. The x is a date format so try `annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, 
                       xmax=as.Date("1975-01-01"), ymin=-Inf, ymax=5)`

Comment: that siad there does seem to be an issue passing two dates for the xmin and xmax, but wrapping in as.numeric seems to fix... ie `annotation_custom(g, xmin=as.numeric(as.Date("1980-01-01")), 
                       xmax=as.numeric(as.Date("1990-01-01")), ymin=-Inf, ymax=5)`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for all of your help. One last quick question. I imported my logo but the image is either just a black box or a white box. How can I resolve that little issue? Lastly, how can I credit you for assisting me with this? The only way I know is via submitting an answer. Thanks again!